# Data not insert into mysql DataBase in php

Tags: php, mysql

DataBase connect but not insert the data into table

**DataBase Name**  School
**Table Name** form

Data successfully insert into mysql sql Consol by using this insert Query  `$sql="insert into form(name,gender) Values('jany','female')";`

and not showing data added Massage also

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","school");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "failed".mysqli_connect_error();

}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$sql="insert into form(name,gender) Values('".$name."','".$gender."')";
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    die('error'.mysqli_error($con));

}
    else echo "data added";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>


<html><head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="">
        Name : <input type=text name=name ><br>
        Last Name : <input type=text name=gender ><br>
        <input type=submit name=submit value=add ><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174). It may also be the cause of your problem.

Comment: 2014 and people still put $_POST in MySQL queries... its amazing. No wonder over a million websites are defaced every year.

Comment: @Havenard then what we use now?

Comment: Put some quotes around your form elements, lordie. Plus, forms default to GET with no method, change `method=""` to `method="post"`

Comment: Have a read ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should switch to prepared statements to get rid of the sql injection problem you have now, but your current problem is caused by the fact that your are not doing a `POST` request, so `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` will always return `false`.

The default method for posting a form is `GET` so change it to:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```